# Display HTML entity in GWT Label

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

In GWT, my code:

```
rootPanel.add(new Label("&copy; " + "2014" + " MyCorp"));
```

Displays nicely:

```
&copy; 2014 MyCorp
```

instead of

```
© 2014 MyCorp
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 6):

I would just do:

```
rootPanel.add(new Label("© 2014 MyCorp"));
```

or using [`HTML`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html):

```
rootPanel.add(new HTML("&copy; 2014 MyCorp"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one also:

```
    Label label1=new Label();
    label1.getElement().setInnerHTML("&copy; " + "2014" + " MyCorp");
```